# How to extract the digits of a number and compute their sum?

Tags: java

```
     y=num%10;
     sum+=y;
     num=num/10;

     System.out.printin(sum);
```

I've got a notation, but I'm unable to understand how it works for calculating the sum, also how to display the numbers being added?
eg. 234 as 9(2+3+4)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is pretty unclear, so I have to make some assumptions about what you're trying to do.

And I'm assuming that you're trying to extract digits from a number and add these digits to each other.

Let's see how is this being done and how does it work...

I must assume that you know what a variable is? Good, so for starters, let's assume that `num` is a variable that holds your number, let's say that we have:

```
int num = 1234;
```

Also let's say we have a variable called `sum` to store our sum of digits. Since this is a sum, it's good to start from `0`. Thus:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Let's see what tools do we have in our toolbox:

- Integral division performed by the `/` operator. Note that this is *integral* division, which means that it rounds down the results. In mathematics we have `1234/10=123.4`; so, since our `/` operator rounds the result down, in Java we will instead get `123`. Thus, dividing a number by `10` has the effect of discarding its rightmost digit.
- Getting the remainder of integral division is performed by the `%` operator. Of course, the remainder of division of `1234` by `10` is `4`. You can see how saying `1234%10` has the effect of retrieving the rightmost digit?

We can now apply both operators to add the first digit to the sum and discard this digit from our number:

```
sum = (sum + num % 10);
num = (num / 10);
```

After executing both above operations, we will have variable `sum` holding `4` and variable `num` holding `123`.

By the way, the `()`s can be discarded:

```
sum = sum + num % 10;
num = num / 10;
```

Also, `whatever = whatever / 10` can be simplified to `whatever /= 10`, same for `+`:

```
sum += num % 10;
num /= 10;
```

Clearly, we have to repeat this process until there are no more digits to discard. Clearly, there are no more digits if and only if `num` equals `0`. (Remember how integral division rounds down? What will happen when we have one last digit to discard, say, `num=5`? In that case `num/=10` would yied `0.5`, but since we are rounding down, it will store a `0` in `num` instead.)

I suppose you are familiar with loops. (If not, I must ask you to read about them). THus, we have an idea for a clear & concise loop:

```
while(num != 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

When this loop stops, the variable `sum` will hold the sum of all digits of `num`, which, in this case, is `1+2+3+4=10`.

EDIT: Printing comes.

Again, let's review the tools in our toolbox:

- `System.out.print()` - this prints whatever you put in the `()`. Note that if you want to print literal text, you must put it in `""`s, or else the compiler will try to figure that your text are variable names really. For example, if you write:

  System.out.print("Alice has ");
  System.out.print("a cat");

You will end up with the following output:

```
Alice has a cat
```

See how we had to take care about the space after "has"?

- `System.out.println()` - Like above, BUT also moves onto another line. For example this:

  System.out.println("Alice has");
  System.out.println("a cat");

Will print:

```
Alice has
a cat
```

We can now add those intructions to our loop to print out each digit:

```
System.out.print("The digits of ");
System.out.print(num);
System.out.print(" sum to: ");
while(num != 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    System.out.print(num%10); System.out.print("+");
    num /= 10;
}
System.out.print("="); System.out.print(sum); System.out.println(".");
```

Oh, wait, there's a problem. This prints:

```
The digits of 1234 sum to: 4+3+2+1+=10.
```

Clearly, we must not add the last `+` if we're processing the last digit. Again, I must hope you're familiar with `if`:

```
System.out.print("The digits of ");
System.out.print(num);
System.out.print(" sum to: ");
while(num != 0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    System.out.print(num%10);
    num /= 10;
    if(num != 0) System.out.print("+");
}
System.out.print("="); System.out.print(sum); System.out.println(".");
```

And this finally produces the desired result and prints:

```
The digits of 1234 sum to: 4+3+2+1=10.
```

Yes, we're printing the digits in a reversed order. If we insist to print them from left to right, we would first have to find the largest power of `10` that is `<=` than `num` and then exctract the digits by getting the remainder of division of `num` by this power of `10`. However, I will leave this as an exercise for You :)